# Docker could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/directory when run on Elastic Beanstalk Local

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gemfile

I'm trying to deploy my docker images on a multicontainer elastic beanstalk environment. The app runs normally when I run it locally using `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. But when I try running the Dockerrun.aws.json file using `eb local run` I get an error saying:

```
 Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
 elasticbeanstalk_app_1 exited with code 10
```

My folder for elastic beanstalk only consists of the Dockerrun.aws.json file. It fetches the database image correctly but fails while loading the app. 
EDIT: I was gitignoring my bundler file 
For reference, these are my files:

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
volumes: 
  postgres-data:
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes: 
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  webpacker:
    build: .
    env_file: 
      - '.env.docker'
    command: npm build
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    ports: 
      - '3035:3035'
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM starefossen/ruby-node:2-8-stretch

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y nano build-essential libpq-dev && \
    gem install bundler

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y yarn

RUN mkdir /project
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /project/
WORKDIR /project
RUN bundle install

COPY . /project
```

> Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
  {
    "command": [
      "bundle",
      "exec",
      "rails",
      "s",
      "-p",
      "3000",
      "-b",
      "0.0.0.0"
      ],
    "essential": true,
    "image": IMAGE_DEST,
    "memory": 256,
    "mountPoints": [
      {
      "containerPath": "/project",
      "sourceVolume": "Project"
      }
    ],
    "name": "app",
      "portMappings": [
        {
        "containerPort": 3000,
        "hostPort": 3000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "essential": true,
      "image": "postgres",
      "memory": 256,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
          "sourceVolume": "Postgres-Data"
        }
      ],
    "name": "db"
    },
    {
      "command": [
        "npm",
        "build"
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "image": IMAGE_DEST,
      "memory": 256,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "containerPath": "/project",
          "sourceVolume": "Project"
        }
      ],
      "name": "webpacker",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 3035,
          "hostPort": 3035
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "family": "",
  "volumes": [
    {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "postgres-data"
      },
      "name": "Postgres-Data"
    },
    {
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/project"
      },
      "name": "Project"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is .bundle gitignored by any chance?

Comment: Yep, that was it.. Thanks a lot!